# JavaScript Using a Loaded Array to Pull data from And display in Text box

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have some code here that will already have data in an array (called setArray). And will loop through that data depending on the length of the transArray and put the random data into the text box fields.  Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/EABRJ/

```
var loadBills = function ()
{

clearFields();

mySetArray();  //Fills the transArray randomly with 1-4 items   

// TEMPORARY ALERT BELOW SO YOU CAN SEE THAT THE ARRAY IS BEING LOADED

//  alert(transArray);      

     for ( var i = 0; i <= transArray.length; i++)
    {
         var items = 'item' + i;
         var amounts = 'amount' + i;    
         splittedData = transArray[i].split(":");
         items.value += splittedData[0];
         amounts.value += splittedData[1];          
    }
}

var clearFields = function ()
{

    for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
     itemName = 'item' + i;
     $(itemName).value = "";
    }
    for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
     amountName = 'amount' + i;
     $(amountName).value = "";
    }
       $('total').value = "";   
   }

var mySetArray = function ()
{

 var myRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) / 25) + 1;  //a number between 1    and 4

 transArray = new Array();  //Resets the Array to empty

 if (myRandom == 1)
 {
    transArray[0] = "Food:200";
 }

 if (myRandom == 2)
 {
    transArray[0] = "Food:200";
    transArray[1] = "Toys:700";
 }

 if (myRandom == 3)
 {
    transArray[0] = "Food:200";
    transArray[1] = "Toys:700";
    transArray[2] = "Mortgage:1800";
 }

 if (myRandom == 4)
 {
    transArray[0] = "Food:200";
    transArray[1] = "Toys:700";
    transArray[2] = "Mortgage:1800";
    transArray[3] = "Cable:130";
 }
}

    window.onload = function ()
    {
    $("loadbills").onclick = loadBills;
        $("clearfields").onclick = clearFields;
    }
```

Comment: You should tell us explicitly what the problem is with your code

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the loadBills function should load the data out of the transArray and split the string and dump it to the html text boxes.

Comment: I don't understand how the spiltted data is supposed to catch the string by splitting data with a delimiter(:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's corrected JS code..

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EABRJ/6/)

```
var loadBills = function () {

    clearFields();

    mySetArray(); //Fills the transArray randomly with 1-4 items    
    // TEMPORARY ALERT BELOW SO YOU CAN SEE THAT THE ARRAY IS BEING LOADED

    console.log(transArray);

    for (var i = 0; i <= transArray.length; i++) {
        if(transArray[i] != 'undefined' && transArray[i] != null) {
            var sdata = transArray[i].split(":");
            $("#item"+(i+1)).val(sdata[0]);
            $("#amount"+(i+1)).val(sdata[1]);
        }
    }
}

var clearFields = function () {

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        $("#item"+i).val("");
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        $("#amount"+i).val("");
    }
    $('total').value = "";


}

var mySetArray = function () {

    var myRandom = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) / 25) + 1; //a number between 1 and 4

    transArray = new Array(); //Resets the Array to empty

    if (myRandom == 1) {
        transArray[0] = "Food:200";
    }

    if (myRandom == 2) {
        transArray[0] = "Food:200";
        transArray[1] = "Toys:700";
    }

    if (myRandom == 3) {
        transArray[0] = "Food:200";
        transArray[1] = "Toys:700";
        transArray[2] = "Mortgage:1800";
    }

    if (myRandom == 4) {
        transArray[0] = "Food:200";
        transArray[1] = "Toys:700";
        transArray[2] = "Mortgage:1800";
        transArray[3] = "Cable:130";
    }
}


$("#loadbills").on("click", loadBills);
$("#clearfields").on("click", clearFields);
```